# Does steps_per_epoch use up the whole dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a large training dataset created by a generator, about 60,000 batches (size 32). Due to the time required for training, I need to use a callback to save the model periodically. However, I want to save it more frequently than once per epoch of 60,000, because that takes about 2 hours on Colab.

As I understand it, setting steps_per_epoch will give me smaller epochs, Say, 10,000. What is not clear to me from the documentation is will this still cycle through my whole 60k batches, or will it stop at 10k and just repeat that 10k? i.e. Does a new epoch start from where the last one left off when using steps_per_epoch?

Thanks, Julian

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know about that option specifically, it wouldn't reuse old data because datasets are only meant to be processed forwards. If it repeated the data, it would have to store a copy of everything it's already processed somewhere since you can't reset a generator. That wouldn't be practical on a large dataset.